# Error when installing mailutils on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, mailutils

When we try to install, remove, update mailutils we always have same  error with status 'half-installed'. Can help me?
The output of:

```
sudo apt install mailutils
```

is:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
mailutils is already the newest version (1:2.99.99-1ubuntu2). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 136 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/90.4 kB of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
dpkg: error processing package patch (--configure):  package patch is not ready for configuration  cannot configure (current status 'half-installed') 
Errors were encountered while processing:  patch 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: first, you need to run 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: OP said the problem occurs when they install, remove, or **update**

Comment: Thank you! 

We used this commands:
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove

And next command fix our problem
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would try the following to attempt a repair:
First, try using `apt` itself to repair the package.

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Then, try re-installing the package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall mailutils
```

If this fails, the next step is to go one level below `apt`, and use `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If all else fails, try removing with `apt`, and then re-installing:

```
sudo apt purge mailutils
```

and be sure to back up any configs you want to keep, just in case.

If even that doesn't work, try `dpkg` again:

```
sudo dpkg --remove mailutils
```

followed by `apt`:

```
sudo apt install mailutils
```

Should that not work, you may have a corrupted `.deb` file cached, or a broken dependency so run:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

and then re-start all the steps.